# How to add all the values of all nodes into one sum in Prometheus/Grafana?

Tags: java, prometheus, grafana, metrics

I have several nodes in Kubernetes that are sending the metric. My task is to display the total number of metrics from all nodes.
Example:
I have[image]
In this case, I expect to get 19.

Answer (score 1):

Change from "round" to "sum" in the PromQL.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but if my statistics are on the MAX field, print the maximum value from the fields for me, in comparison with my screenshot it's just the number 18.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you.